# Issue with VPN to enable CI system and accessing MACs for Visual studio developement

Tags: continuous-integration, vpn, synology, l2tp, linksys

I am trying to setup build servers, and a mac available for remote builds in VS. As results I have a Synology server setup with VPN enabled. The Firewall and all settings are setup according to the [synology guide](https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/help/VPNCenter/vpn_setup). I have then enabled port forwarding on my linksys WRT1900ACS router, for the three ports needed (500,1701,4500), which is also enabled in the firewall on the router. I then access the VPN locally without any issues, tried with different guides ([guide1](https://www.synology.com/da-dk/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/Application/How_to_connect_to_Synology_s_VPN_Server_using_a_Windows_PC_or_Mac) [guide2](https://www.cactusvpn.com/tutorials/how-to-set-up-l2tp-vpn-on-windows-10/) [guide3](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SettingUpAVPNAndRemoteDesktopBackIntoYourHomeWithASynologyFromAnIPhone.aspx)).

I then create copies of the vpn connection and inserting my static IP from my ISP. I logon to a tethered internet from my phone, as to ensure the network is different. I then get an error:

> local l2tp connection attempt failed because the security layer encountered a processing error during initial negotiations.

Searching it seems like it is an error with the registry ([reg 1](https://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?t=95121) [reg 2](https://www.wijngaard.org/l2tpvpn/)). Changing that just makes the vpn connection hang. What am I doing wrong? After waiting a long period of time (several minutes), the same error returns.

I have also tested on an Ipad using the settings defined in [ios-settings](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SettingUpAVPNAndRemoteDesktopBackIntoYourHomeWithASynologyFromAnIPhone.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others the above guides solves the issue if you have a static IP. You however have to ensure that your ISP, have allowed the traffic, and that your router does not receive a double IP registration, rendering your static IP invalid.

which was the case for me.